# I get an error while using this command i don't know why?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

ALTER USER kalyan CREATEDB;

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATEDB' at line 1
```

Comment: For 1 it's not valid syntactically and your db is complaining about that. For 2. What do you expect this command to do? I have no idea.

Comment: i am trying for unit test in django. Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'kalyan'@'localhost' to database 'test_equalserp'")

Answer (score 0):

delete your database if you have data inside db. If you have data, back it up.
Otherwise, fix the sql code of the table.